# Why is my visual studio 2008 project read-only

Tags: visual-studio-2008, intellisense

I'm working on a project for school, we use visual studio 2008 there and I use it at home, both are express edition. The project in question I started at school, but I cannot edit it at home, when I open the .sln I get this

"The IntelliSense information will not be available for .VC++ projects because the Intellisense database file Location/Junk.ncb could not be opened for writing.

Other features will also be affected if the solution directory is read-only."

How do I open my project so that I can edit it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your solution directory writable, right-click on the solution directory, select Properties, and uncheck the Read-Only checkbox in the dialog that opens.

Comment: So this is the problem I use a portable hard-drive, and the directory is read-only, but when I uncheck the box, hit apply, give administrative permission and click ok it immediately resets back to read-only.

Comment: You'll have to copy the directory to your local hard drive, and work on it there.

Comment: I tossed it onto my computer and it works, its weird because I can work on it off my hard drive at school without problem.

Answer (score 5):

Two suggestions:

- Make sure you don't already have the solution open in Visual Studio (this may sound dumb, but you can't open a solution in two Visual Studio instances at the same time)
- Delete the Junk.ncb file (this file is generated by Visual Studio; it will be recreated when you reopen the solution).

Comment: The first item is particularly likely - check the taskmanager process list for devenv.exe instances which may not be showing any UI but might be holding on to files.

Answer (score 2):

- It's open somewhere else?
- You saved the solution on a CD and copied the files to your hard drive?  (I have to change the attributes manually on my files because the read-only attributes transfer to the copies on the hard drive.)
- It's checked in under source control?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you already have this solution open in another Visual Studio window.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an instance of Visual Studio hang up and didn't response but it still held Junk.ncb